# Sending location to emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am testing the option to send coordinates to the Android Emulator using the Built in Eclipse tool.But it doesn't seem to receive them.I have this simple code:

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    final MapController mp = view.getController();

    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(), (int)location.getLongitude()));

        }
    };
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

I have the permissions for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and INTERNET in the Manifest.
If someone has any explanation I would be grateful.

Comment: I hate to give this blanket answer, but, if it's not working, you're doing something wrong in regards to the emulator.  It's probably not in your code.

Comment: And what are the possible wrong things?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best advice I can give you is to research exactly how this is supposed to be done and find where you are deviating from it.  Also, a google & SO search will give a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

to the application tag in the manifest?
You also need a MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate from Google to receive Google Maps data. You can get it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey?hl=de-DE#getdebugfingerprint).

Try to put a breakpoint inside the onLocationChanged method and see if it stops when sending the location command to the emulator. this should also work when you don't have a certificate yet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to stop in the onLocationChanged...Any idea why??

Comment: Did you add gps support for the Emulator? Go to avd manager and click edit on the avd. Then add gps support entry in the "hardware" section.
When you send location data to the emulator you should see the gps icon in the notification bar.

Comment: I am seeing that icon, but the location doesn't change :(

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Listener implementation...

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public static final String TAG = "MyLocationListener";

    private Context context;

    public MyLocationListener(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG,"LocationChanged: Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+" Lng: "+location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
```